# Why can't counsel-rg index an expression previously found?

Tags: ivy, grep, counsel, error, ripgrep

I am using trying to use a command called `counsel-rg`. This is the associated `describe-command`:

```
counsel-rg is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘counsel.el’.

(counsel-rg &optional INITIAL-INPUT INITIAL-DIRECTORY EXTRA-RG-ARGS
RG-PROMPT)

Grep for a string in the current directory using ‘rg’.
INITIAL-INPUT can be given as the initial minibuffer input.
INITIAL-DIRECTORY, if non-nil, is used as the root directory for search.
EXTRA-RG-ARGS string, if non-nil, is appended to ‘counsel-rg-base-command’.
RG-PROMPT, if non-nil, is passed as ‘ivy-read’ prompt argument.

Example input with inclusion and exclusion file patterns:
    require i -- -g*.el
```

Although the definition does not mention it, for me I use this command as an interface of `ripgrep`.

It is a command that **helps me find stuff** on the code base.

There is a weird behavior happening, though.

If I type to search `"Book`, I can see:

[image]

As you see, one of the results retrieved is `"Book JE"`. Hence, I tried to search for it:

[image]

This feels weird to me since the output does **not** show the result that I was expecting to see. In addition, as you see, the mini-buffer indicates that an "error code 2" happened.

1. Why is this happening? Why I can't index an expression that was actually previously found?
2. What is an "error code 2"?

Obs.: If this is relevant, this is my [init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el) in Emacs. And I am using Macbook Air M1 Monterey 12.6.

UPDATE

I tried the approach suggested by [db48x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9982/db48x), but it did not work out:

[image]

[image]

**Observation**: Follow another suggestion that appeared on the comment section, I also tried writing `(trace-function 'call-process)` on the scratch buffer, putting the cursor after the last parenthesis, and executing the command `eval-last-sexp`. It returns `nil`.

Comment: I meant that you should try searching for `"Book\ JE"`. What does that give you?

Comment: Thanks again for the help, @db48x. Unfortunately, the problem persists. I have updated the question with the suggested approach.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot. You should figure out a way to see what arguments are given to rg. Try running `(trace-function 'call-process)` in the *scratch* buffer.

Comment: Do you mean writing ` (trace-function 'call-process) ` in the scratch buffer, putting the cursor after the last parenthesis, and executing the command `eval-last-sexp`? I did that and it returns `nil`. Thanks for another iteration!

Comment: Yes. Now try your search again and a trace buffer will appear that shows you when the `call-process` function was called, and with what arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is now solved with the following addition to my init file:

```lisp
(setq ivy-re-builders-alist '((counsel-rg . ivy--regex-plus)
                              (t . ivy-prescient-re-builder)))
```

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1823) helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the man page for `rg`, you will find that the exit status will be 2 when there was an error. This can be a syntax error in your search regex, or an error while reading some file (a disk error, permissions, etc).

You should debug this problem further by figuring out what arguments this passes to rg. I wasn’t able to get `counsel-rg` to work on my first try, so I cannot really help you much there.

However, my guess would be that the space is breaking your search into two arguments, one of which is then being treated as a file name by rg. Since that file doesn’t exist, rg exits with status 2. Try escaping it with a `\`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your suggestion (if my interpretation is correct), but it did not work out. I documented my attempt updating my question.

Comment: I believe I solved the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
use `[ ]` for a single space

```lisp
rg: "Book[ ]JE"
```

[image: rg book je]